# Selected value from dropdown menu doesn't select when click on button in php

Tags: php, mysqli, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I am selecting data from two table "pizza" and "size".In "pizza" table we have a fields name "pizza_id , pizza_name , pizza_img" in "size" table  "pizza_id , size_id , size , price". When we select the the first pizza and their sizes in "size" table are small , medium and large.It shows in drop-down menu.The problem is that when we click on first size of pizza(small) and click on button it shows that u are selecting last (large) size of pizza.Every time i m selecting any size of pizza, it shows that u are selecting large(size_id:3) size of pizza.So i dont no how to fix that.If anyone can understand my problem than please help me i m badly stuck.Thank u

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pizza";
  $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

        $pizza_id = $row['pizza_id'];
        $pizza_name = $row['pizza_name'];
        $pizza_img = $row['pizza_img'];

  echo "<div class='pizza_details'>
  <img src='admin/img/$pizza_img' width='200px' height='150px'  
  id='profile-image' />
  <div class='desc'>
  <ul>
  <li><span style='color:yellow;'>Name</span> : $pizza_name</li>
  </ul>";


  $q = "SELECT * FROM size where pizza_id='$pizza_id'";
  $r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

  echo "<select name='size'>";

  while ($new=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

          $size_id = $new['size_id']; 
          $size = $new['size'];
          $price = $new['price'];

   echo"<option value='$size_id'>$size</option>";

   }//End-while loop

   echo"</select>
   <ul><li>
   <a href='pizza.php?add_cart=$pizza_id&size_id=$size_id'>Add to Cart</a>
   </li></ul>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>";

  }//End-While Loop
```

Comment: How are you getting the $pizza_id for sizes? Is this really your code all in php in this flow? You are not taking any user inputs. In your Add to Cart link you have basically hard coded the pizza_id and size_id as the last value in loop.

Comment: Basically $pizza_id in pizza table are primary key and in size table are foreign key. So in size table the $pizza_id are store in three rows. All the sizes the $pizza_id in "size"  table are same but its $size_id are different and when we click on add to cart link it get the selected size value and send to the cart.

Comment: I understand the database. But you are not collecting user's selection/input anywhere. The flow should be to show list of pizzas, when user selects a pizza you submit the value (via form or ajax) and use the selected pizza id to decide which size, then dynamically create the URL for add to cart with currently selected pizza id and size id. You are not collecting and submitting any user actions. Just a link with hard coded last ids.

Comment: Thank u so much, i hope your guidance is worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <form action="" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
    <select class="form-control" id="a_set_of_values" name="a_set_of_values" >

    <?php

      $q = "SELECT * FROM size WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
      $r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

      while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
            $size_id = $rows['size_id'];
            $size = $rows['size']; 
            $price = $rows['price'];
    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $size_id;?> & <?php echo $price; ?>"><?php echo $size;?> : Rs <?php echo $price;?></option>

    <?php } ?>

    </select>
    <button class="read_mor_btn"  type="submit" name="add_cart" title="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>

    </form>
```

Now get all these values (product_id, size_id, price) from above and used explode function to get multiples values in select option.

```
    //Pick these values
    if(isset($_POST['add_cart'])){

    $product_id= $_POST['product_id'];

    $explode_fun = $_POST['a_set_of_values'];
    $new_data = explode(' ', $explode_fun);
    $size_id = $new_data[0];
    $price = $new_data[2];    
    }

    ?>
```